# Finding matching pairs (intersection) of values between two 2D arrays?

Tags: python, numpy

I have two arrays:

```
arr1 = np.array((
    np.array([ 32,  32,  32,  32,  32,  39], dtype=np.int64),
    np.array([449, 451, 452, 453, 454, 463], dtype=np.int64)))
arr2 = np.array((
    np.array([ 39,  34,  32,  32,  37,  32], dtype=np.int64),
    np.array([463, 393, 453, 452, 261, 449], dtype=np.int64)))
```

In these 2D arrays, the:

- First array (`arr1[0]`, `arr2[0]`) are **x-axis** values
- Second array (`arr1[1]`, `arr2[1]`) are **y-axis** values

I would like to find the **xy pairs** that match between the two arrays.

Some clarifications:

- `arr1` and `arr2` will not necessarily be of equal length. They could be different lengths
- **X value** and **Y value** pairs could be in any ordering. Sorting or alignment between arrays is not expected
- Duplicates of the same **X value** and **Y value** pairs will not occur in the same array

In the above examples, the pairs that are the same between the two arrays are:

- X = 32, Y = 449
- X = 32, Y = 452
- X = 32, Y = 453
- X = 39, Y = 463

I've tried to use `np.intersect1d` and some other functions I found.

Comment: Off-topic, but why do you do nested arrays? Why not just `np.array([[...], [...]], dtype=np.int64)`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a structured array.

```
import numpy as np

# Define a dtype with x and y integers    
arr1 = np.empty(6, dtype=[('x', int), ('y', int)])
arr2 = np.empty(6, dtype=[('x', int), ('y', int)])

# Add the data to the structured array
arr1['x'] = np.array([ 32,  32,  32,  32,  32,  39])
arr1['y'] = np.array([449, 451, 452, 453, 454, 463])

arr2['x'] = np.array([ 39,  34,  32,  32,  37,  32])
arr2['y'] = np.array([463, 393, 453, 452, 261, 449])
```

Use intersect1d:

```
>>> np.intersect1d(arr1, arr2)
array([(32, 449), (32, 452), (32, 453), (39, 463)],
  dtype=[('x', '<i8'), ('y', '<i8')])
```

Comment: Just to be clear, `6` is the size of the arrays in this example, but it should be changed for other cases. Like, if you built off of OP's data, you'd do `arr1.shape[1]` and `arr2.shape[1]`, or something like that.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Before accepting your answer, I was wondering if there is an efficient way to apply this to say 10 arrays, where I would need to know the intersection between each of those 10? Finding the same x,y pairs that occur in each of those 10 arrays?

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you're asking for - you want the intersection of 10 arrays, or you want to make 90 pair-wise intersections?

Comment: So, the same way I have the 2 2D arrays, and finding the pairs that are common between them, I wanted to see how you would recommend finding the pairs that are common between more then 2 2D arrays, such as 10 2D arrays, where dimension 1 are x-axis values and dimension 2 are y-axis values

Comment: Sorry I explained that incorrectly, I have 2 separate arrays representing the data, not 2D arrays

Comment: Same arrays I have in the example, except instead of 2, there are 10

Comment: If you built a list `lst = [arr1, arr2, arr3, arr4 ... arr10]` of structured `x`/`y` arrays you could intersect all of them with `import functools` and `functools.reduce(np.intersect1d, lst)`

Answer (score 0):

Since you need to find the intersection of couples, in my opinion it's better to use the `set` data structure instead of `numpy.array`:

```
np.array(list(
    set(zip(*arr1)).intersection(zip(*arr2))
))
```